# How do I configure spacemacs for python 3?

Tags: python, emacs, spacemacs

I would like to use spacemacs for python development, but I see a syntax error on Python 3 constructs, like `print(*(i + 1 for i in range(n))` or `async def foo():`. Adding a shebang to my file (`#!/usr/bin/python3` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`) does not help.

What configuration changes do I need to make to use a specific python version? Ideally per-project or per-file, but global is better than nothing. I have 2.7 and 3.4 installed system-wide, and 3.5 in `~/local` (`~/local/bin` is in my `$PATH`).

Comment: I don't know much about Spacemacs, but are you using virtual environments?

Comment: @Chris only if the required python packages are not available in the debian repositories (so mostly no).

Comment: holy....... at last, I found I just does not install pylint for py3:`pip3 install pylint`, after that, everything works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable that needed to be set was `flycheck-python-pycompile-executable`, to `"python3"`.

To get support for `async`, `emacs25` must be used (note debian will install `emacs24` and `emacs25` side-by-side, and use `emacs24` by default).

Comment: How do you set that variable and where should you set it?

Comment: The easiest way is `SPC-SPC`, `customize-variable`, `flycheck-pycompile-executable`. I'm sure it can be set in your dotfile, check [the docs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org) for that.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to change spacemacs configurations. You can just use pyenv to manage python version.

Install `pyenv` then in terminal

```
$ pyenv install 3.5.1
$ pyenv global 3.5.1
```

Default python interpreter will be set to python 3.5.1.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.1
```

For more details see [here](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).

Plus, set `python-shell-interpreter` to `python3` may also fix the problem.

Comment: Where is the python-shell-interpreter variable located?

Comment: @oliver Use `SPC h d v` you can check the variable's current value. You could change it in your configurations directly by set this variable to another value.

Comment: FWIW, setting `python-shell-interpreter` fixed issues I had where the wrong python version was used